# Scanner for hex-input not working as expected inside loop

Tags: java, hex, java.util.scanner

I need to solve this problem where i need to convert hexadecimal numbers to decimals.

#### Issue

I have compiled it without any errors, but my output came out wrong. Can someone show how to fix these errors?

### Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class HexToDecException extends Exception  {
   
    public HexToDecException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static int hexToDec(String hex) throws HexToDecException {
        char currentChar;
        int dec=0;
        int power = 0;
    
        for(int i=hex.length()+1;i>=0;i--){// by reverse
            currentChar = hex.charAt(i);
           
            if(currentChar>='0' && currentChar<='9'){
                dec+= Math.pow(16,power)*(currentChar - '0');
                power++;
            }
            else if(currentChar>='a' && currentChar<='f'){
                dec+= Math.pow(16,power)*(currentChar - 'a' + 10);
                power++;
            }
            else if(currentChar>='A' && currentChar<='G'){
                dec+= Math.pow(16,power)*(currentChar - 'A' + 10);
                power++;
            }
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Character in Hexadecimal string");
        }
        
        return power;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = null;
        try{
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                System.out.println(hexToDec(scan.next()));
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        finally{
            System.out.println("That's all.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example

Input:

```
5 6B 5 4AZ A5 9
```

Expected Output:

```
107  5 Invalid hexadecimal number 165 9
```

Output that i got:

```
That's all
```

Comment: Why the convoluted approach? There is the `Integer.parseInt(str, 16)` to parse hex. Also put the try-catch around the individual parsing so the loop can continue when the current string is invalid.

Comment: What is this line for? int n = scan.nextInt();
It's probably the reason why it won't work as for example, if your file contains AB5 H67 5, it will read the 5 and then there would be no next string

Comment: @Sebastian it's how many numbers will be input, hence the `5` in the example input. The code seems to be fine (for homework standards) provided your algorithm works, for some reason your loop isn't getting executed I guess.

Comment: oh yeah, just saw it! @idk what to write here you can try the best debugging method in the world, just print a few lines ;) add an output for your n variable to make sure that everything fine with it and test if the hexToDec() method is ever called

Comment: A few issues to address.. your initial loop condition will not work: `(int i = hex.length() + 1`, need to change that to "`- 1`" or the index will be invalid every time. Also, re-work the `try` block.. the thing that might throw an exception is `hexToDec()`, so wrap that call in a `try-catch` – if anything is caught, print out the message in the exception (`ex.getMessage()`).

Comment: Also, `hexToDec()` is returning `power` which is incorrect, it should return the number you're constructing along the way, so: `return dec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is close. Here are changes to make so that it runs correctly:

- modify the `return` statement of `hexToDec()` to return the decimal number you've constructed, not the power, so change this: `return power` to this: `return dec`
- modify `throws` clause to this: `throw new HexToDecException("Invalid hexadecimal number");` – use the custom exception you defined, and edit the string message to match the output you're expecting
- change the `for` loop in `hexToDec()` so it that properly checks each position in the input string, so change this: `for (int i = hex.length() + 1` to this: `for (int i = hex.length() - 1`. Maybe read up on how [`String.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length()) works in relation to [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)). If a string has a length N, the corresponding "Nth" position in that string has to be referenced by N-1. N itself would never work, and N+1 would also not work.
- finally, rewrite the main loop to wrap the call to `hexToDec()` in a `try-catch`, and print the exception message if an exception is thrown:

  ```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = scan.nextInt();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      String nextInput = scan.next();
      try {
          int x = hexToDec(nextInput);
          System.out.print(x + " ");
      } catch (HexToDecException e) {
          System.out.print(e.getMessage() + " ");
      }
  }
  ```

After those changes, this input:

```
5 6B 5 4AZ A5 9
```

will produce this output:

```
107 5 Invalid hexadecimal number 165 9
```